# How to do explicit conversion of FLOAT to a VARCHAR field in SQL

Tags: sql, sybase

I'm getting a query from a column float (with no precision) and inserting it in another table and comumn float (with no precision as well) but I'm getting this error:

> Error (265) **Insufficient result space** for explicit conversion of FLOAT value '3.8833137793643' to a VARCHAR field.

The query:

```sql
INSERT INTO TableA
SELECT DISTINCT max(price_1) AS PriceValue
FROM TableB
```

Comment: How is your varchar field defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does may or may not answer your question.  But the query should be written as:

```
INSERT INTO TableA (<column name>)
    SELECT MAX(price_1) AS PriceValue
    FROM TableB;
```

Notes:

- An aggregation query with no `GROUP BY` returns exactly one row.  `SELECT DISTINCT` is not necessary.
- You should include the columns being inserted.

Your problem is clearly that the column is not wide enough.  If you have defined the table as:

```
create table tableA (
    col varchar
);
```

Then **you have not specified a length** and are depending on the default in the database.  Do you even know what the default is?  In this case, it is `1`.  And that is not long enough for your value.  You just need to provide a long-enough length:

```
create table tableA (
    col varchar(255)
);
```

All that said.  I strongly discourage you from storing number values as strings.  That is likely to create problems now and in the future.  Use the appropriate types for your data.